# Search between 2 dates with different format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a column name is db_datetime with type is datetime 
the date is stored like this in the database

[image]

for the search i use a date picker the format of this date picker is like this

```
09/19/2016 M/d/Y
```

i want to search between two dates and search on the name with a drop down menu and search in character or number
i use this code but the problem is with the date i use `STR_TO_DATE` but it didn't give me a result all my effort didn't success always give me no result for my search and i have a dates stored for what i search
this is the code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $search=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_search']);
    $q = array();  
    $sql = "";     
    if(isset($_POST['txt_name']) && !empty($_POST['txt_name'])){  
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_name']); 
    $q[] = " db_name='".$name."' ";      
    }  
    if(isset($_POST['txt_psd']) && !empty($_POST['txt_psd'])){  
    $psd=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_psd']); 
     $q[] = "STR_TO_DATE($psd, '%Y-%m-%d') like'%db_datetime%' ";    
    }   
    if(isset($_POST['txt_pdd']) && !empty($_POST['txt_pdd'])){  
    $pdd =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_pdd']); 
    $q[] = "STR_TO_DATE($pdd, '%Y-%m-%d') like'%db_datetime%' ";      
    }     
    $qq=array();
    if(isset($_POST['txt_search']) && !empty($_POST['txt_search'])){  
    $search =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_search']); 
    $qq[] = "db_name like '%".$search."%' "; 
    $qq[] = "db_datetime like '%".$search."%' "; 
    $qq[] = "db_user like '%".$search."%' "; 
    } 
    $first = true; 
    $second=true;
    foreach($q as $qu){  
        if($first){  
        $sql .= " where ".$qu;      
        $first = false;  
        }else{  
        $sql .= " and ".$qu;          
        }} 
       foreach($qq as $qu){  
        if($second){  
        $sql .= " where  ".$qu;      
        $second = false;  
        }else{  
        $sql .= " or ".$qu;          
        }}  
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_login {$sql}")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Re-format the date so it's compatible with the mysql one. I wouldn't be surprised if the date picker didn't have this inbuilt functionality

Comment: Try something like this:

 `$dte = str_replace('/', '-', $post_data['date']);
 $dt = new DateTime();
 $date = $dt->createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dte);
 $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');`


I had a similar problem, replace the vars with your's.

Comment: @James111 how i reformat the date ?

Comment: @DenisSolakovic not working the input change the date

Comment: you need to convert the data into that format using strtotime and Date function and use EQUAL TO instead of LIKE for date

Comment: @HarshSanghani can you please give me an example

Comment: you need to convert the data from db as well: `$q[] = "STR_TO_DATE($pdd, '%Y-%m-%d') like STR_TO_DATE(db_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') "; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can covert the user input date into `Y-m-d` format as supported by MySQL in PHP then pass that date into mysql.

> Edited

```
$userInput = '09/19/2016';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $userInput);
$newDate = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
echo $newDate; //output will be : 2016-09-19
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['txt_psd']) && !empty($_POST['txt_psd'])){  
    $psd=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_psd']);
    $userInput = $psd;
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $userInput);        
     $q[] = "db_datetime=$date";   
    }   i use your code but it give me that Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @mhmd: I have updated my code please check it, I have just assign a date into variable and tested it by `is_string` function which return true. So now you will not get the mentioned error.

Comment: that what i have for print the sql where db_datetime=2016-09-19 no result. and this is the code      if(isset($_POST['txt_psd']) && !empty($_POST['txt_psd'])){  
    $psd=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_psd']); 
    $userInput = $psd;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $userInput);
$newDate = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
echo $newDate;
   $q[]="db_datetime=$newDate";

Comment: Replace the last line with this `$q[]="db_datetime='$newDate'";` you have missed single quote.

Comment: this what i have where db_datetime='2016-09-19'no result.

Comment: @mhmd: this is how it works, you might be having error in your sql query. try this one also. `db_datetime` = '2016-09-19'; i mean surround db_datetime with back quote.

Comment: i use like and it give me a result but = not give me result

Answer (score 0):

Your idea for the STR_TO_DATE function is wrong. Obviously, it needs the *input* date format, not output (which is already known). So the following should work

```
STR_TO_DATE('$psd', '%m/%d/%Y') = db_datetime
```

note that your idea of using LIKE is wrong as well.

Comment: didn't work i try your solution and this solution STR_TO_DATE('$psd', '%Y/%m/%d') = db_datetime and this solution STR_TO_DATE('$psd', '%Y-%M-%d') = db_datetime

Comment: why on the earth would you try a '%Y-%M-%d' format? How it's ever related to your 09/19/2016 date?!

Comment: it should be lower "m" by the way.

Comment: on the database it look like that

Comment: **But you you are converting not your database value but input value.**

Comment: It is not about making your code work, as it may not work for the thousand other reasons. It's about answering your question on converting the date format.

Comment: i echo the sql and it give me that where STR_TO_DATE('09/19/2016', '%m/%d/%Y') = db_datetime no result.